# Hashing raw audio data

Tags: audio, directx, signal-processing, hash, decoding

I'm looking for a solution to this task: I want to open any audio file (MP3,FLAC,WAV), then proceed it to the extracted form and hash this data. The thing is: I don't know how to get this extracted audio data. DirectX could do the job, right? And also, I suppose if I have fo example two MP3 files, both 320kbps and only ID3 tags differ and there's a garbage inside on of the files mixed with audio data (MP3 format allows garbage to be inside) and I extract both files, I should get the exactly same audio data, right? I'd only differ if one file is 128 and the other 320, for example. Okay so, the question is, is there a way to use DirectX to get this extracted audio data? I imagine it'd be some function returning byte array or something. Also, it would be handy to just extract whole file without playback. I want to process hundreds of files so 3-10min/s each (if files have to be played at natural speed for decoding) is way worse that one second for each file (only extracting)
I hope my question is understandable.

Thanks a lot for answers,

Aaron

Comment: Presumably this is a Windows-specific question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://sox.sourceforge.net/ (multiplatform).  It's faster than realtime as you'd like, and it's designed for batch mode much more than DirectX.  For example, `sox -r 48k -b 16 -L -c 1 in.mp3 out.raw`.  Loop that over your hundreds of files using whatever scripting language you like (bash, python, .bat, ...).